# Magento CSV import listing images

Tags: php, magento, csv

I use a CSV file to import products to my magento store, everything goes quite well untill i open the listing-page.

Magento auto selects the "No image" to all the listing-options at Thumbnail, small image and base image. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

The `image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail` are all set with exampleimage.jpg (path is right).

Answer (score 0):

You should check 'store' column on you csv, it should be usually - 'default'

Comment: There are set to base (website) and default (store). Products are added right.

Answer (score 0):

if you create an array for the import add this lines at the end:

```
            'image'                   => 'img1.jpg',
            'small_image'             => 'img2.jpg',
            'thumbnail'               => 'img3.jpg'
```

this map the images to the specific image type. In your csv you add this 3 columns in addition:

*,"image","small_image","thumbnail",*
*,"img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img2.jpg"*

cheers