# Importing Images Magento

Tags: php, image, magento, csv

I use a CSV file to import products to my magento store, the images gets in and are assigned to the correct SKU, but Magento.
Magento auto selects the "No image" to all the listing-options at Thumbnail, small image and base image.

I know i should use the _media_position and set it to 0. But I get "invalid row"-error.
In order to get that to work, I need to set the _media_attribute_id, but I can't find what the id is.

Theese are the columns i have in the CSV:

```
Price   
Special_price   
Stock.qty   
Name    
SKU 
category.ids    
manufacturer    
Description 
short_description   
image   
small_image 
thumbnail       
url_key visibility  
product.attribute_set   
product.type    
product.websites    
stock.is_in_stock   
weight  
tax_class_id    
status  
supplier_sku
```

Am I missing something, and where do I find the id I need for _media_attribute_id. 
My images are in the media/import - folder

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some code or explanation what you tried

Comment: Have tried to make new columns in the CSV.
Like: sort_order, store_view with differnt values like 1, true, default.
What captilize letters and none.

Somehow i need to tell in my CSV, that Magento schould pick the "right view" for the images.

Hard to explain, when I can't post pictures.
This guy here has the same problem..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297645/magento-csv-import-listing-images

Comment: provide a sample csv format with data which you are using.

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaahhhhhhh FACE-PALM!!

Was in the wrong store view!